# Frequent 'EBUSY' errors using NextJS 13's built-in fetch

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Since migrating from NextJS 12 to `13.4.9` and from `axios` to the now built-in `fetch`, I've started frequently getting `EBUSY` errors on the server side. These don't seem to break anything at first glance:

```
Failed to update prerender cache for [SOME_LONG_ID] [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open 'C:\[REDACTED]\.next\cache\fetch-cache\[SOME_LONG_ID] {
  errno: -4082,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\[REDACTED]\\.next\\cache\\fetch-cache\\[SOME_LONG_ID]'
}
```

```
Failed to update tags manifest. [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open 'C:\[REDACTED]\.next\cache\fetch-cache\tags-manifest.json'] {
  errno: -4082,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\[REDACTED]\\.next\\cache\\fetch-cache\\tags-manifest.json'
}
```

I've also seen the `EPERM` error on a few occasions. It happens quite rarely but this one kills the process:

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\[REDACTED]\.next\trace'
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\[REDACTED]\\.next\\trace'
}
```

Has anyone experienced similar issues with NextJS 13?

I've already tried running VS Code & the terminal as an administrator with no luck.

`Node v18.15.0`